# Making ConditionalExpression as a Function to use

Tags: conditional

i have these functions:

```
savA[k_, s_, a_] := s*a*k^0.5;
savB[k_, s_, b_, c_] := s*b*k^(0.5) - c;
depr[k_, n_, d_] := (n + d)*k;
```

`savA` and `savB` intersect at `(c/(b - a))^2`. so what i plot is `savA` for `0 < k < (c/(b - a))^2` and `savB` for `(c/(b - a))^2 <= k` as ContionalExpression:

```
ConditionalExpression[savA[k, s, a], 0 < k < (c/(b - a))^2], 
ConditionalExpression[savB[k, s, b, c], (c/(b - a))^2 <= k]
```

Is there a possibilty to define these two `ConditionalExpression`s as one new function?

This is what i want to implement and why there is a problem:

```
ConditionalExpression[0, Or @@ Thread[depr[k, n, d] < {savA[k, s, a], savB[k, s, b, c]}]],
```

so, whenever `depr[k, n, d]` is smaller than either one of the `sav`Functions `0` should be plotted. But since `depr[k, n, d]` can intersect `savA`, for example, `depr[k, n, d]`is < and > than `savA`.

Comment: Would `Piecewise` help?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like the following?

```
condExp[k_, s_, a_, b_, c_, n_, d_] := 
 ConditionalExpression[0, Or @@ Thread[depr[k, n, d] < {savA[k, s, a], savB[k, s, b, c]}]]

Manipulate[Plot[{savA[k, s, a], savB[k, s, b, c], depr[k, n, d], 
      condExp[k, s, a, b, c, n, d]}, {k, 0, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[0], ColorData[54, "ColorList"][[1]]], 
     Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[0], ColorData[54, "ColorList"][[2]]],
     Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[0], ColorData[54, "ColorList"][[3]]], 
     Directive[Red, Thick, Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}] ]}] /. Line -> Arrow, 
 {{a, 1.66}, 1, 10}, {{b, 4.75}, 0.5, 10}, {{c, 2.75}, 0, 10}, 
 {{s, 0.5}, 0.5, 1}, {{d, .25}, 0, 1}, {{n, .25}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can define the function `condExp` using `If` or `Piecewise` on the right hand side of the definition:

```
If[Or @@ Thread[depr[k, n, d] < {savA[k, s, a], savB[k, s, b, c]}], 0, ## &[]]
```

or

```
Piecewise[{{0, Or @@ Thread[depr[k, n, d] < {savA[k, s, a], savB[k, s, b, c]}]}}, ## &[]]
```

You can use `Nothing` in place of `##&[]` if you have Version 10 or a newer version.